# error: each element of 'ext_modules' option must be an Extension instance or 2-tuple

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to use setuptools in python to create an egg package, but I get this weird error:

```
error: each element of 'ext_modules' option must be an Extension instance or 2-tuple
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The relevant `setuptools` issue: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/309

Answer (score 45):

I had to reorder import statements to get rid of this error. This code generates the error:

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
```

This code does not generate the error:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
```

Edit: This works because setuptools monkey-patches distutils, and setuptools must therefore be the first one to import distutils.

Comment: ..but WHY did that solve the problem for you?

Comment: setuptools monkey-patches distutils, and must therefore be the first one to import distutils.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Please add this to your answer because that is the key to why it works.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming that you already have setuptools installed,
Edit setup.py of the egg package target
and replace the `import setup, Extension` in order to get them from setuptools.

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, Command
```

Rational: setuptools redefines `Extension` so it's possible that it does not recognize the object that you have in the **ext_modules** argument as a valid Extension object. Hence the error message.

**ext_modules** is one of the arguments of setup() method that describe the extension of your module, and it's specified in setup.py.

```
setup(name='foo',
  version='1.0',
  ext_modules=[Extension('foo', ['foo.c'])],
  )
```

[More info available in Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to conflict with distutils from where the Extension is imported w.r.t setuptools. I see this error when installing gdsCAD so I had to update the setupext.py to sucessfully install

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not use combination of `distutils` and `setuptools` if you are using `find_packages`. This order generates error:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from setuptools import find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize
```

So you should use `setuptools`'s implementation of `find_packages`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
```